# Is it a good idea to make an AJAX call on <a> click before taking the user to the href location?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a few scenarios where on a click of `<a>` element on a page I need to send some data to the server with AJAX and if everything is fine take the user to where `<a>` is pointing.

Here is the flow:

1. User does something on the page.
2. User clicks `<a>` element.
3. AJAX call goes to the server, server processes the request, sends the response.
4. If response is all good -> navigate, if some error -> return false from JavaScript, thus abort navigation and display error message.

So, I'm just wondering, is this generally a good or a bad practice and why?

Comment: Does the ajax call actually make any changes on the server, or is it simply verifying that things are ok? If it's a simple verification, a better option is to simply NOT show the link in the first place, until conditions are correct.

Comment: @Marc B - It's actually saving a few things to DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules regarding such issues, but one common rule of thumb is that `<a>` links shouldn't be used for POST-like actions such as updating a database. So ask yourself what the AJAX call does: if it simply requests some data from the server, it is okay to do this with an `<a>`; if it causes some sort of update to occur, consider using a `<button>` instead.

Comment: I agree.  In a perfect world, I would have AJAX calls happen on a page level on button clicks and what not.  And only redirect the user from a navigation menu or a link without any AJAX involved.  Unfortunately, business usually doesn't care about web development best practices ;)

Comment: @Dimskiy: Think of it this way: is it okay to navigate to the link without performing the AJAX call? This is what would happen if JavaScript is disabled, and your business logic shouldn't go wrong because of this.

Comment: @casablanca - "is it okay to navigate to the link without performing the AJAX call?" The answer is Yes.  By "business" I mean people who make decisions such as "this page has only 1 'button' and by clicking on it the data is saved and the user is taken somewhere"

Comment: @Dimskiy: In that case, I don't see a problem with your current setup. However, why would you abort navigation if the AJAX call is not important?

Comment: @Dimskiy: Unfortunately that happens way too often as business managers have no idea of what they're asking for.

Comment: @Casablanca - I removed my last comment.  Wasn't a "nice" thing to say :)  Thanks a lot for your input!

Answer (score 1):

In the past, if a link has an onClick method, I've always done away w/ the href altogether.  In your AJAX onClick method, just handle the logic within the method and, when needed, call Window.Location inside the method to load a new URL.

Comment: I used to do it this way too.  However, I find this new method more 'solid' I guess...  The navigation is based on HTML, not JS.